# How do I enable/disable spellcheck in pidgin on windows?

Tags: windows, instant-messaging, pidgin

How do I (temporarily) disable the spellchecker in pidgin on windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools - Preferences - Conversations - "Highlight mispelled words"

Comment: @Nikhil Exactly what i was gonna say